# Limit checkbox selection in SharePoint Online Survey

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, checkbox

I've been pulling my hair out trying to find a solution to this problem! I have a SharePoint Online Survey, that contains five questions where the respondent can check up to six checkboxes per question. However, for two of those questions, I need to limit the number of boxes a user can check, to three. The code below will limit every checkbox in the survey to three selections, and I can't figure out how to target just the two questions that need to restrict to three boxes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
jQuery(function(){
var max = 3;
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

checkboxes.change(function(){
    var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
});
```

});

Comment: You can add a `class` attribute to the 2 specific checkboxes with `max=3`. And add an additional `.className` to the jQuery selector. Then duplicate the code as you have now for `max=6`. If you get that to work you can think of a way to refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint puts the checkboxes in a specific html structure so you could try traversing the structure to get the questions name and target the question in this way e.g.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
   var questionText = $(this).closest('table').closest('tr').prev().find('td').text();

   if(questionText.trim() == 'Question 1'){
      //do stuff
      alert(questionText);
  }
});
```

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6cdswd6/)

Comment: Thanks everyone, for your suggestions. The person I was working on this for decided to cancel the survey, but it's good to know what options are available, as I know this will come again.